# Creating a series of dropdown boxes from a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem that I just can't think of a logical way to overcome. I have a table similar to this:

```
+-------------+--------------+---------------+
|  id         |  catName     |  parentId     |
+-------------+--------------+---------------+
|  1          | Category 1   |  0            |
|  2          | Category 2   |  0            |
|  3          | Sub Cat 1    |  1            |
|  4          | Sub Cat 2    |  1            |
|  5          | Sub sub cat 1|  4            |
|  6          | Sub sub cat 2|  4            |
|  7          | Category 3   |  0            |
+-------------+--------------+---------------+
```

I need to write a PHP function to output a series of dropdown boxes with the parent category selected. For example:

If I pass the function the id `5` the following HTML structure will be output:

```
<select name="level-1">
   <option selected="selected">Category 1</option>
   <option>Category 2</option>
   <option>Category 3</option>
</select>

<select name="level-2">
   <option>Sub Cat 1</option>
   <option selected="selected">Sub Cat 2</option>
</select>

<select name="level-3">
   <option selected="selected">Sub sub cat 1</option> // This is the category with id=5
   <option>Sub sub cat 1</option>
</select>
```

It was hard to find a way ask this question, so If I haven't made myself 100% clear please don't down vote me, just ask and I'll explain

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is not particularly hard. Fetch/build the parent category, then a loop to fetch/output each child category...

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet, I can't think of the logic behind it

Comment: Anything, I literally have no idea where to begin with this. It's driving me insane!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php  in that case? We can help with specific questions here. Not a "don't know what to do, so please do it for me" type things.

Comment: I'm not asking for anyone to do it for me, just point me in the direction I should be taking

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to build a recursive function, something like the following:

```
function recursive_dropdown($category_id) {
    $category = // fetch category from database
    echo '<option value="'. $category['id'] .'">'. $category['name'] .'</option>';

    $parent = // fetch it's parent
    if( // parent exists ) {
        return recursive_dropdown($parent['id']);
    }
    return true; // done!
}
```

--- edit this is basic recursion, you'll have to tweak it for your needs... principle is the same

Comment: I can't get this working :S could you expand this answer please?

Answer (score 0):

I like to use a helper function when I need to generate a dropdown menu.

This PHP function:

```
function CreateDropdown($name, $array, $selected="")
{
    $result = "<select name='$name'>";

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $result .= "<option value='$key'";
        if ($key == $selected)
            $result .= " selected='selected'";
        $result .= ">";
        $result .= $value."</option>";
    }

    $result .= "</select>";
    return $result;
}

echo CreateDropdown('level-1',
                    array(1=>'category 1', 2=>'category 2', 3=>'category 3'),
                    3);

?>
```

generates this HTML:

```
<select name='level-1'>
    <option value='1'>category 1</option>
    <option value='2'>category 2</option>
    <option value='3' selected='selected'>category 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in some like that:

```
$id = 5; // Your ID

// DB data => ID - Description - Category
$data = array(
1 => array("Category 1",    0),
2 => array("Category 2",    0),
3 => array("Sub Cat 1",     1),
4 => array("Sub Cat 2",     1),
5 => array("Sub sub cat 1", 4),
6 => array("Sub sub cat 2", 4),
7 => array("Category 3",    0));

$dds = array(); // Array that will hold the result

function reverse_recursively($id, $data, &$dds)
{
    $dd = "<select>"; // Open select tag
    $cat = $data[$id][1]; // Find the current category

    foreach ($data as $i => $d) // Fetch data
    {
        if ($d[1] == $cat) // If is in the category
        {
            $sel = $id == $i ? " selected='selected'" : "";

            // The option tag
            $dd.= "
                <option value='$i'$sel>" . $d[0] . "</option>";
        }
    }

    $dds[] = $dd . "</select>"; // Close select tag

    if ($cat != 0) // Category 0(zero) means the end so it have to be diferent to proceed.
        reverse_recursively($cat, $data, $dds);
}

reverse_recursively($id, $data, $dds);

// In each DDS item you got the dropdown ;-)
foreach ($dds as $dropdown)
{
    echo $dropdown . "<br /><br />";
}
```

But you have always to try to face your problems 'till the end, if all your sweat runs out, then you call for help. Otherwise you'll never grow your programmer abilities. Think about...